# problem with $conf['i18n_variables']

Tags: i18n-l10n

i have installed i18n module and added this lines to setting.php and empty cache to translate slogan and contact form information and  ... 
but it doesnt affect site and values dont add to i18n_variable table.

```
$conf['i18n_variables'] = array(
        'site_name',
        'site_slogan',
        'site_mission',
        'site_footer',
        'anonymous',
        'user_registration_help',
        'user_mail_welcome_subject',
        'user_mail_welcome_body',
        'user_mail_approval_subject',
        'user_mail_approval_body',
        'user_mail_pass_subject',
        'user_mail_pass_body',
        'contact_form_information'
    );
```

do you have any suggestion to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually go to the page in the admin that updates the variable and edit it from the non-default language url.

For example, with site name, if you have one other language with 'es' as a path prefix you would go to 'http://example.com/es/admin/settings/site-information' and change the site name. Once you do that in another language it will create the variable in the i18n_variable table.

You will know you are on the right track when the element you want to update in the admin says "This is a multilingual variable"

Comment: i cant see "this is a multilingual variable" for site slogan in site information although i add this to setting.php

Comment: are you sure internationalization is turned on? what happens if you 'dpm(variable_get('i18n_variables'));' ?

Comment: i18n is enabled (turn on is another thing?). and what is  dpm(variable_get('i18n_variables'))?

Comment: Any luck? The devel module http://drupal.org/project/devel will give you some general tools to help you work. "dpm" or "Drupal Print Message" will spit out a variable in an easy to read format. If you install and enable devel you could go to http://mysite.com/devel/php and type "dpm(variable_get('i18n_variables'));" and see if the i18n_variables is getting set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `drush` you can check what is the actual value of `i18n_variables`.

```
drush variable-get i18n_variables
```

If the list is different from what you put into `settings.php`, it means that there is another statement in `settings.php` or one of the modules that is overriding the variable.

One [common cause](https://www.drupal.org/node/313272#comment-5719530) is having `Internationalization tests` module enabled. This module overrides `i18n_variables` with

```
$conf['i18n_variables'] = array_merge(array('site_name', 'site_frontpage'),
              variable_get('i18n_variables_test', array()));
```

Unless `i18n_variables_test` is also set, you would only get `site_name` and `site_frontpage`.

If this is the case for you disable `Internationalization tests` module in the `Testing` section of *Administer -> Site Building -> Modules*.